# Equal height columns in css except one column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to create equal height cards using flexbox or any other methods in css. But one of those cards will have a ribbon on top of the card. That will be set dynamically in react.

So I need to create equal height cards except one. Something like below,

An example is here,
https://codepen.io/andichamy-ga/pen/MGJPXv

HTML:

```
  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended one"></div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
      bar<br>
      foo
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended">Recommended Card</div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended one"></div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
      bar
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.some {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.recommended {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.one {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I tried in many different ways. But none of those seems like a proper way. How can I do this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the top ribbon to be absolute position and rely on flexbox for the remaining to have equal height:

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.some {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  position:relative;
}

.recommended {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  height: 40px;
  top:-40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.one {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height:100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended one"></div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br> bar
      <br> foo bar
      <br> foo  bar
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended">Recommended Card</div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended one"></div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br> bar
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That does the trick. setting the absolute position for recommended div and also 100% height for box div.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like a price table, more in number like below.
https://jsfiddle.net/rdggv429/

```
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
<p style="text-align:center">Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Basic</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 9.99 / year</li>
    <li>10GB Storage</li>
    <li>10 Emails</li>
    <li>10 Domains</li>
    <li>1GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns special">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="special-li">Special</li>
    <li class="header" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Pro</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 24.99 / year</li>
    <li>25GB Storage</li>
    <li>25 Emails</li>
    <li>25 Domains</li>
    <li>2GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Premium</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 49.99 / year</li>
    <li>50GB Storage</li>
    <li>50 Emails</li>
    <li>50 Domains</li>
    <li>5GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>





    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.price .header {
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.special-li {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

If you want the header dynamically, give it on the page load, append the LI to the first element on the UL

Comment: Using position: absolute and top: -60px works, but I want the rest of the cards to have the equal height. If I add some more content in one of the cards, the height of the remaining cards should match the longest card's height.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="some-all">
 <div class="some">
  <div class="recommended one"></div>
   <div class="box">
      foo<br>
       bar<br>
       foo
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="some">
  <div class="recommended">Recommended Card</div>
  <div class="box">
    foo<br>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="some">
  <div class="recommended one"></div>
   <div class="box">
    foo<br>
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

use css

```
<style>
 .some-all{display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
   .some-all .some{  
   background-color: green;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that can be possible with flexbox, but this could be a possible solution for your question, hope it might help you.

You can also view it on Codepen: https://codepen.io/techyogi/pen/ervNWW

**CSS**

```
$blue: #a3d5d3;

body {
  background-color: $blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.some {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

.recommended {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.one {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended one"></div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
      bar<br>
      foo
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended">Recommended Card</div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <div class="recommended one"></div>
    <div class="box">
      foo<br>
      bar
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works. but change the height to 100% for box div

Comment: @AndichamyGA Hope that worked for you, I'll update my code, Thank you!